# Cannot load SWFs larger than 32768 bytes

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have an ActionScript 3 project in which I'm using a `Loader` to load external SWFs. In Chrome, the Flash Player will not fire `Event.COMPLETE` if the size of the SWF is greater than 32768 bytes! Any idea why or how to work around this issue?

I tried to use `ProgressEvent.PROGRESS` and execute the logic when `event.bytesLoaded == event.bytesTotal`. This works, it does get there, but then `loader.contentLoaderInfo.applicationDomain.getDefinition()` can't find the class inside the SWF.

Comment: May be this is the limit (though I have failed to find any documentation regarding this). If that is the max allowed size, then you may need to split this big SWF to multiple SWFs.

Comment: @taskinoor, the SWF does eventually load. While listening for `ProgressEvent.PROGRESS`, I can see that it loads and it arrives at the point in which `event.bytesLoaded == event.bytesTotal`. However, `Event.COMPLETE` is never fired. This issue only happens in Chrome.

Comment: Could be a chrome bug too. I also want to see a solid answer of this question.

Comment: @taskinoor, could be. The progress workaround is working, but I suppose Flash does something extra before emitting `Event.COMPLETE` which lets me instantiate classes from the SWF. Maybe there's another way I can do that that would work in the callback I use to listen for `ProgressEvent.PROGRESS`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that this problem only occurs if the event listener is added as a weak reference. Removing the weak reference solved the problem.

Comment: Yes, it's probably a case of the garbage collector removing your Loader before it finishes. I think Flash Player has a special case where a Loader with a strong event listener will stay in memory (even though that's the opposite of how referencing is supposed to work. the dispatcher holding a reference to something else should not keep the dispatcher in memory). A better way would be to have something else reference the Loader. A member variable on your class is good, or you can add it to the display list.